# Overcoming views dependencies when importing

Tags: mysql, view, import

I am going to import a lot of views from my old mysql server. There is a lot of dependencies between views and tables and other views. MySQL does not allow creation of a view unless tables and views it references are created in advance. How can I import my views? Is there any way to disable dependency checking while importing?

Comment: How are you exporting? `mysqldump` handles this.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I used HiediSQL. Is it documented? Do you have any link? How does it handle this? Does it order queries according to the dependencies?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11596711/168493 and http://lists.mysql.com/internals/37267